# Cannot find the URL to my Strapi Media Library

Tags: next.js, graphql, render, strapi, cloudinary

So, I hosted my strapi app on Cloudinary and Render. So there is a rich text input in my strapi backend. When i fetch the data using graphql, the images are sent out as URLs ofc. So when i host strapi in my localhost, the url is this, http://localhost:1337/uploads/Expressjs_706596c597.png. But when my app is hosted and is running, then also it is receiving http://localhost:1337/uploads/Expressjs_706596c597.png from the backend. Now that image does not exist as my localhost is not running. But when I try this this, *renderURL*/uploads/Expressjs_706596c597.png the image is still not there. So Where can I find the exact URL of my image?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When hosting your Strapi app on Cloudinary and Render, the URLs of the images served by Strapi will no longer be the local `http://localhost:1337` URLs. Instead, you should be using the URLs provided by the Cloudinary integration. The URL provided by Cloudinary should have a format similar to `https://res.cloudinary.com/<your-cloud-name>/image/upload/<version>/<your-image-file.jpg>`.

By using this Cloudinary URL, you can retrieve the image from anywhere, including your hosted app. Replace the `http://localhost:1337` portion of the URL with the appropriate Cloudinary URL, and you should be able to access the image successfully.

Comment: Where can I find this thing "v1234567890"?

Comment: It's just the version number, it will work without the version number too.